# Failed connection with .sqlite file in QGIS converted from osm by spatialite

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have converted a *.osm file to a *.sqlite file using the spatialite_tool i.e sspatialite_osm_map..

Now I want to view the map using QGIS.  However, at the time of using the add spatialite table option I am getting an error:

> Failure while connecting .sqlite file - seems to be a valid SQLite DB,
>   but not a SpatiaLite one ...

Answer (score 3):

The spatialite OSM tools write to a spatialite v4 database. Unfortunately, QGIS 1.8.0 is not able to read this database version.

You can try `spatialite_convert` from [this  page](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/) to convert the database back to v3, which should be readable with QGIS.

See also

[Can't open Spatialite db from openstreetmap in Quantum GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52586/cant-open-spatialite-db-from-openstreetmap-in-quantum-gis)

[Why are layers imported into a DB with Spatialite-Gui locked from editing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60991/why-are-layers-imported-into-a-db-with-spatialite-gui-locked-from-editing?rq=1)

https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=switching-to-4.0